# PDF extract specific pages & merge with new filename

Tags: batch-rename, pdftk, windows-scripting

I have 2 pdf files (templates) from which I need to extract 1 page each and save as a combined pdf. Each pdf has a filename with a different 3 letter location indicator (e.g. LOC) for each of the agreement pdfs. I'm looking for a way to batch process these and save with the location indicator in the new combined filename. There are approx 500 locations.

Example files:

```
Agreement1_LOC.pdf - extract pg 3
Agreement2_LOC.pdf - extract pg 1
Agreement1_AAA.pdf - extract pg 3
Agreement2_AAA.pdf - extract pg 1
```

Save as LOC_combined.pdf (in same or new dir)

I'm looking for a way to batch process or loop through a directory.  If it's easier, I have a list of all the filenames in .csv.  I'm sure it could be done in python, powershell, or even batch file but I'm not very familiar with these. Trying to learn with real life example.

Using PDFtk pro, I can do it one at a time.

```
pdftk A=Agreement1_LOC.pdf B=Agreement2_LOC.pdf cat A3 B1 output LOC_combined.pdf
```

I found batch files for merging but none that save with portion of original filenames.

Comment: I have replaced your tags for three different scripting languages, with a single one. If you want help with code in a specific language, [Edit] your question to include the code for the language you'd like us to help you with, and replace the [[tag:windows-scripting]] tag with only the appropriate one. Your question is currently, not focused on a specific scripting issue, and reads just like a code request. There are examples of how to perform loops in [tag:powershell], [tag:batch-file], and [tag:python], all over this site. Use the search facility at the top of the page to find and adapt one.

Comment: Yes, I have a list of locations that could easily be one location per line text file.  As I am not a programmer, I am not sure best/easiest method to achieve this.  I think batch file is easiest and am looking at loops and trying to understand syntax and how to use variables. Thanks.